# MVC custom login authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

Hi I'm developing an app in MVC and I have a problem with login, I want to know how can I manage the login depending on the user role.

While the moment the login works fine but I need to identify the role user for sending to different pages

I have a table in my database call Employee and one column is call IdPosition that is referred to another table call Position.

Here is my code

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Autorizacion(Pepitos.Models.Employee employee)
    {
        using (pepitosEntities db = new pepitosEntities())
        {
            var userDetails = db.Employees.Where(x => x.Username == employee.Username && x.Password == employee.Password).FirstOrDefault();

            if (userDetails == null)
            {
                employee.ErrorLoginMensaje = "Username or Password incorrect";
                return View("Login",employee);
            }
            else
            {
                Session["IdEmployee"] = userDetails .IdEmployee;
                Session["name"] = userDetails.Name;
                return RedirectToAction("EmployeesIndex", "EmployeesHome");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: you can add conditions after setting the session to redirect specific pages for specific role, although you need to create filter to check custom authorization for each request.

Answer (score 0):

Now what you need to do is check the role after the username and password matches and then redirect accordingly.for that i assumed you have role column in your database table along with username and password.

```
 using (pepitosEntities db = new pepitosEntities())
    {
        var userDetails = db.Employees.Where(x => x.Username == employee.Username && x.Password == employee.Password).FirstOrDefault();

        if (userDetails == null)
        {
            employee.ErrorLoginMensaje = "Username or Password incorrect";
            return View("Login",employee);
        }
        else
        {

            var userRole=userDetails.role; //get the role of the user i.e whether user is admin or any other role

            if(userRole=="Admin")
            {
               Session["IdEmployee"] = userDetails .IdEmployee;
               Session["name"] = userDetails.Name;
               return RedirectToAction("EmployeesIndex","EmployeesHome");
            }
            else if(userRole=="User")
            {
                Session["IdUser"] = userDetails .IdUser;
                Session["name"] = userDetails.Name;
                return RedirectToAction("UserIndex","UserHome");
            }
            //and so on
        }
    }
```

hope it helps!