# How to get UserID from the current logged in user if you are not using Individual User Account template in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, userid

I know there is User.Identity.GetUserId(),but i think that you can use it only if you are using Individual User Account template,since i'm not using it,i have a custom login and registration actions,i would like to know can you set up the Identity to read my user's id from the database and how.So this is my model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;

namespace jaj.Models
{
    public class user
    {
        public string profilePicture { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public HttpPostedFileBase userInfo { get; set; }


    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Username required")]
    public string Username { get; set; }



    [Display(Name = "Email ID")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Email ID required")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [MinLength(6, ErrorMessage = "Minimum 6 characters required")]
    public string Password { get; set; }



    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Confirm password and password do not match")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Favorite Tag")]
    public string FavTag { get; set; }





}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MVC custom login authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431706/mvc-custom-login-authentication)

Comment: If i understood that right, i can save all the details about the user with var userDetails = db.Employees.Where(x => x.Username == employee.Username && x.Password == employee.Password).FirstOrDefault(); and then store the id into a session?